# Is "hack" still a valid uiExport type in Kibana 4.5?

Tags: plugins, kibana, kibana-4

I'm currently experimenting with plugin development for Kibana v4.5.0. The documentation for plugin dev on Kibana, while sparse, lists "hacks" as a valid uiExport type ([documentation](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/wiki/UiExport-Types)).

However, whenever I attempt to create a plugin (creatively named "plugin_name") with a uiExport type of "hacks"...

**index.js**

```
export default kibana => {
  return new kibana.Plugin({
    uiExports: {
      hacks: [
        'plugins/plugin_name/hack'
      ]
    }
  });
};
```

**...the Kibana dev instance crashes with the following error:**

```
FATAL [Error: unknown export types hacks in plugin plugin_name]
```

From which, I assume that the "hacks" type is no more. There was an issue opened back in March that seems to relate to this problem ([link](https://github.com/elastic/generator-kibana-plugin/issues/28)), but it has since been closed with no resolution.

**Has this uiExport type been changed or removed in Kibana?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In v4.5, "hacks" is no longer a valid UiExport type. However, it was added into v5.0.

Version 4.5: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/4.5/src/ui/UiExports.js#L47

Version 5.0: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/5.0/src/ui/ui_exports.js#L86

"hacks" is missing from the switch statement within UiExports.js in v4.5, but is present within v5.0.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/bd258ac34f3d65a8cf0c2fef5f816890007d3fe3/src/ui/ui_exports.js), it is still a valid type. The error you got occurs when you don't define a visualization of that type.

Is `plugins/plugin_name/hack` a visualization of type 'hacks'? Or maybe forgot to register it?

Comment: That's the master of the Kibana project...I found that "hacks" is in that file in v5.0 and following; however, it was missing from version 4.5 and lower.